# How to fallback_fonts.xml work in android?

Tags: android, fonts, fallback

I see fallback_fonts.xml declares fonts use in android system but I don't know how it working.
Can anyone can talk to me about "How to fallback_fonts.xml work in android?"
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

fallback_fonts.xml is the list of font names

### Hope this would be easy to understand:

### the name fallback_fonts.xml implies the meaning about "fallback". That when the phone (or the application) cannot find the suitable fonts in the system font to display your website (or your text or whatever), the phone will come looking inside the fallback_fonts.xml and find the suitable font to display (orderly from top down),if cannot find any suitable font, the phone will then cannot display properly the text, probably will display the square for each unknown character.